# .Generic casting to do test inputs for a Method

Tags: java, generics, methods, casting

I need help casting a string into different variable types using a generic. What I am trying to make is something to help beginner coders learn by giving them a class with incorrect implementation of methods or with just the skeleton (only Method names nothing else) and having them fix it, and then testing the class and each method against a rubric class with the same methods. In the rubric class test inputs for each method are given as comments but i can't find a way of casting the inputs from strings into the desired types. I can get the desired types by using `Method.getGenericParameterTypes()` and setting a generic equal to that but when I try casting using that it doesn't work...
Here is my code for this:

```
    name = className.substring(0,className.indexOf("Copy"))+"Rubric";
    String param = ReadWrite.readData("src/"+name+".java").get(methLoc);
    Type B = meth.getGenericReturnType();
    Type E;
    Type [] params = meth.getGenericParameterTypes();
    String [] para = param.substring(param.indexOf("(")+1,param.indexOf(")")).split(",");
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class myClass = null;
    Object obj = null;
    classNamer();
    try {
        myClass = Class.forName(name);
        obj = myClass.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (params.length != para.length) {
        Console.log("Rubric test parameters are wrong");
    }
    else if (obj==null){
        Console.log("Error instantiating objects");
    }
    else {
        Object [] parames = new Object [params.length];
        for (int i =0; i<para.length; i++) {
            E = params[i];
            parames[i] = ((E)para[i]);
            System.out.println(params[i] + " " + para[i] + " " + parames[i] + " " + parames[i].getClass() + " " + E);
        }
        try {
            B rtrn = (B) meth.invoke(obj, parames);

            B rtrn2 = (B) testMethods[testNum].invoke(obj, parames);

            if (rtrn.equals(rtrn2)) {
                count++;
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I apologize for how hard my code is to read, if you need to know what I am trying to do anywhere just ask ill try to clear it up.
And `Console.log` is something I use to print stuff to a console I made as part of the visuals.

Comment: If I understand this right, you're trying to convert strings into objects of arbitrary types? What are some examples of the input strings and their intended types?

Comment: Yes That is what I am trying to do, an example would be converting  "(1,1)" into two ints or Integers with a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do with `Type E` isn't possible, you can't make a generic type variable in a method and cast to it. More importantly, casting does not convert an object into another object of a different type, it just tells the compiler to assume the object is already the type you're casting to. At runtime, if the object isn't really that type, you'll get a `ClassCastException` thrown.

What you need to do is *parse* strings into objects of various types, so that the runtime type of the object matches the method parameter. The compile-time type can just be `Object`, since `Method.invoke` takes them as `Object[]` anyway.

```
public static Object parseParam(String str, Type type) {
    if (type.equals(String.class)) {
        return str.replaceAll("^\"(.+)\"$", "$1"); // assumes strings are quoted
    } else if (type.equals(int.class) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
//  } else if (type.equals(...)) {
//      return ... // implement more as needed
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Class not supported: " + type);
    }
}
```

See here for more info: [Parsing Objects from String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018570/parsing-objects-from-string-in-java) (note that the accepted answer won't work for classes that don't have a `String` constructor). You may want to consider storing the values as fields in the testing classes instead, or serializing them, or using some sort of testing framework. Once you have this implemented, something like this should work:

```
name = className.substring(0, className.indexOf("Copy")) + "Rubric";
String input = ReadWrite.readData("src/" + name + ".java").get(methLoc);
Type[] params = meth.getGenericParameterTypes();
String[] para = input.substring(input.indexOf("(") + 1, input.indexOf(")")).split(",");
Class<?> myClass = null;
Object obj = null;
classNamer();
try {
    myClass = Class.forName(name);
    obj = myClass.newInstance();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (params.length != para.length) {
    Console.log("Rubric test parameters are wrong");
} else if (obj == null) {
    Console.log("Error instantiating objects");
} else {
    Object[] parames = new Object[params.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
        parames[i] = parseParam(para[i], params[i]); // convert string to object
        System.out.println(params[i] + " " + para[i] + " " + parames[i] + " " + parames[i].getClass());
    }
    try {
        Object rtrn = meth.invoke(obj, parames);

        Object rtrn2 = testMethods[testNum].invoke(obj, parames);

        if (rtrn.equals(rtrn2)) {
            count++;
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```